# Comando AddSchema en un XMLReader en Genexus

Tags: java, genexus

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Genexus Evolution 2 U7, para java y tengo un problema con el comando AddSchema del tipo de datos XMLReader.

Tengo un procedimiento que tiene una validación de un XML contra un XSD, 
que cae en la siguiente linea:

```
&XMLReader.AddSchema(&Xsd.Trim(), Obt_ScHEMA_NAME())
```

dónde `&Xsd` es una variable de tipo `varchar(256)` de la ubicación del 
archivo xsd en el disco y el procedimiento `ObtObt_ScHEMA_NAME()` devuelve 
un string con el namespace.

Capturando las excepción con java, lo único que devuelve es lo siguiente:

```
http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation/
```

Ya he hecho el rebuild de todo, y probado mil cosas. La gente de Artech no me contesta y ya no sé qué más probar.

Alguien tiene idea que otra cosa puedo intentar ?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el soporte de validación de XML contra Schema esté disponible en su  aplicación Java tiene que utilizar la última implementación de Xerces.

El SAC de ARTech [#17868](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/main21/hscver21.aspx?S%3B15%3B4%3B61%3B2%3B1%3BO%3B,2,17868) indica como proceder para tener disponible dicha implementación.-

Por favor observe lo que allí se menciona respecto a:

- utilizar la VM de Sun
- agregar en el classpath el xercesImpl.jar
- poner la gxclassr en el directorio common\lib
- poner el xerces en el directorio common\endorsed